# Code doesn't wait for Callback Function Completion

Tags: javascript, function, callback, console, timeout

I am new to Javascript coming from Java and want to write a Function who acts like a Java Method. 
The Problem is that the calling Code doesnt wait for the called function to finish and just continues what occurrs errors. i hope you understand what I'm talking about. Maybe you can help me

```
if (Titanium.Facebook.loggedIn) {
        // User is not logged in with his ACS Account but with its Facebook Account
        // now we can check if he has an ACS Account with the same eMail Address
        Titanium.API.info('User seems to be logged in to Facebook');

        gFacebookAccount = gFacebookController.getLoggedInFacebookAccount();
        Titanium.API.info('Logged In Facebook Account is : '+ gFacebookAccount); }
```

The called getLoggedInFacebookAccount looks like this. i tried to delay the method by a timeout loop what doesnt work.

```
exports.getLoggedInFacebookAccount = function()
{
Titanium.API.info('Started getLoggedInFacebookAccount');
var lCallBackFinished = false;
var lActualUser = null;
Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me', {}, 'GET', handleGraphRequestCallback);

waitForQueryCallback();


function waitForQueryCallback() {
    if (!lCallBackFinished) {
        Titanium.API.info('Wait for Query Callback Loop');
        setTimeout(waitForQueryCallback, 100);
        //
    }
    else
    {
        return lActualUser;
    }
}


function handleGraphRequestCallback(pGraphCallback) {

// damn callbacks - now here the user is logged in
// and the Graph Request is (sucessfully or not) finished

Titanium.API.info('Start handleGraphRequest-Callback');
if (pGraphCallback.success) {
    Titanium.API.info('Graph Request Callback Sucessful');
    lActualUser = pGraphCallback.result;

} else {
    Titanium.API.info('Graph Request Callback Not Sucessful');

}

lCallBackFinished = true;

}

}
```

The Console Output is :

```
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] User seems to be logged in to Facebook
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Started getLoggedInFacebookAccount
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Wait for Query Callback Loop
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Logged In Facebook Account is : undefined
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Function called
[ERROR][TiJSError(  301)] (main) [214,2413] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR][TiJSError(  301)] (main) [0,2413] - In undefined:1,1

[ERROR][TiJSError(  301)] (main) [0,2413] - Message: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
[ERROR][TiJSError(  301)] (main) [1,2414] - Source: undefined
[ERROR][V8Exception(  301)] Exception occurred at undefined:1: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Wait for Query Callback Loop
[INFO][TiRootActivity(  301)] (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity resume. activity = de.dosofun.knowitall.Knowitall2Activity@44ede8f8
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Wait for Query Callback Loop
[INFO][ARMAssembler(   60)] generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x3666d0:0x36678c] in 4662744 ns
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Wait for Query Callback Loop
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Wait for Query Callback Loop
[INFO][ActivityManager(   60)] Displayed activity de.dosofun.knowitall/.Knowitall2Activity: 5509 ms (total 5509 ms)
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Wait for Query Callback Loop
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Wait for Query Callback Loop
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Wait for Query Callback Loop
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Wait for Query Callback Loop
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Start handleGraphRequest-Callback
[INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Graph Request Callback Sucessful
```

cause of line: [INFO][TiAPI   (  301)] Logged In Facebook Account is : undefined
you can see that the code doesnt wait until the called method is finished.

What is necessary so my code works as wished and if my code is very bad, what is a better way (which is not to confusing to read)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does it return 'lActualUser' directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
wait_var = waitForQueryCallback();
YOU ARE NOT HANDLING THE RETURN FROM waitForQueryCallback() here...

function waitForQueryCallback() {
if (!lCallBackFinished) {
    Titanium.API.info('Wait for Query Callback Loop');
    setTimeout(waitForQueryCallback, 100);
    //
    RETURN SOMETHING HERE?
}
else
{
    return lActualUser;
}
}
```

Try and handle wait_var from waitForQueryCallback() and return something if callback isnt finished.