# webservice call fails for second time - backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Its bit strange, the fist time the webservice call gets called, but from second time onwards i get this strange error.

```
this.save(requestObject, {
    success: function (response) {
        callback(response.toJSON());
    },

    error: function (res, result, xhr) {

    }
});
```

The first time i get the callback, why from second time it fails? Below is the error log.

```
HTTP Error (org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException): 596
    [ERROR][TiHttpClient(  478)] org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: 596
    [ERROR][TiHttpClient(  478)]    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$LocalResponseHandler.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:240)
    [ERROR][TiHttpClient(  478)]    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$LocalResponseHandler.handleResponse(TiHTTPClient.java:199)
    [ERROR][TiHttpClient(  478)]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
    [ERROR][TiHttpClient(  478)]    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:637)
    [ERROR][TiHttpClient(  478)]    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1217)
    [ERROR][TiHttpClient(  478)]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
    [ERROR][V8Exception(  478)] Exception occurred at undefined:1: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: The problem is likely to be on server side. Are you sure that the first call doesn't induce side effects such that consequent calls fail?

Comment: @Y__: How can we check that the first call is not making any impact.

Comment: Can you trace the response from the server to the client in the first and second cases ? Without any code from server side it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Y__: the second time it does not even get into the onLoad call... i mean the success call.

Comment: Yes, but what I meant is that the problematic code does not seems to be the `JavaScript` part that you did post but your `Java` code on server side. At least the exception comes from it.
This question http://stackoverflow.com/q/11598836/667433 may help you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `save` for the first time, what does the client sends back to the server? A POST request or a PUT request? The second time, does the client request changes or is it the same?

This may help you identify the problem. Backbone `save` method delegates to the `Backbone.sync` method which decides the type of request it should make. For example, using the `isNew()` model method, `sync` makes a POST (because a new model has to be saved on the server) request if the model is new or a PUT request (a model update) if the model already exist. You can check more information regarding the `sync` method at [backbone main page.](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)

The error you are getting from the server might be happening because it does not know how to respond to one of this request. It might worth checking it out.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the backbone.js documention](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save):

`If the model isNew, the save will be a "create" (HTTP POST), if the model already exists on the server, the save will be an "update" (HTTP PUT).`

So basically the first request will be a POST request and all other requests afterwards will be a PUT request. Since it appears your server-side script is having setup to handle PUT requests, you will probably want to use the [emulateHTTP](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateHTTP) setting like so:

```
Backbone.emulateHTTP = true
```